# jsPDF show print page instead of downloading the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

hi i've an issue can anybody tell me how to display the print page in browser instead of downloading the file. i'm using **jsPDF** library.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
pdf.text(30, 30, 'Hello world!');
pdf.save('hello_world.pdf');
```

here's an example code.
when i run this it downloads the file but don't show the print page. all i want is to show the print page instead of downloading the file then printing it.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use doc.output()

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
 doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
 doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
 doc.addPage();
 doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

// Output as Data URI
 doc.output('datauri');
```

**CHROME**

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

var base64string = doc.output('datauristrlng');
debugBase64( base64string );

function debugBase64(base64URL){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
```

Comment: yes it did work but it requires reload to the opened page on chrome but works fine on firfox

Comment: You can use following solutions for chrome `function debugBase64(base64URL){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}` and `var base64string = doc.output('datauristrlng');` to save output into variable, then just call `debugBase64(base64string);`

Comment: yep it worked for both browsers just need to put 'bloburl' instead of 'datauristrlng'.